# Python - Move Elements to the End of a 2-Dimensional Array?

Tags: python, list

Given this 2D Array - [[0, 0, **-1**], [1, 0, **-2**], [2, 0, **-3**], [3, 0, 0]]

How can I code something in Python that moves everything to the end? (If the end is empty).

So I get something like this - [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, **-1**], [2, 0, **-2**], [3, 0, **-3**]]

I tried something like this:

```
count = 0
while count < row: # row is 4 in this case. 
    if my_array[row-1][2] == 0:
        tp = my_array[count][2]
        my_array[count][2] = 0
        my_array[count+1][2] = tp
    else:
        break
    count += 1
return my_array
```

But this is what I get instead:
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]]

Update:

Thanks @furas, I spent hours trying to figure this out
How can I also handle a gap in the middle? So if I get something like this:

```
data = [[0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]]

expected = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]]

rows = len(data)

if data[-1][-1] == 0:
    count = rows-1
    while count > 0:
        data[count][-1] = data[count-1][-1]
        count -= 1
    data[0][-1] = 0

print(data)
print(expected)
print(data == expected) # False
```

Thanks

UPDATE Nov.29 -

I have certain scenarios like these that don't work? Can you help?

**DATA**: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

**EXPECT**: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 2, 0]]

Or if it's negative:

**DATA**: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [-101, -101, -101, 0], [2, 3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 3, 0]]

**EXPECT**: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 3, 0]]

Thanks A lot!!

Comment: instead of `[row-1]` you can use `[-1]` to get last row. BTW: use `print()` to display values in variables during moves.

Comment: you moves from first to second, then from second to third so you overwrite  values. You have to move from second to third and later from first to second.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that the length of my list is not always the same. Currently, the length is 4 but it can also be 5/6/7. So I need to do something that will essentially push everything back one if a '0' is present at the end or even in the middle.

Comment: Do you only want the last column to be shifted, or do you want all columns to shift like that and you only gave the last column as an illustration?

Comment: You should show your new example at start - now better create new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something like this

```
def move(data):  
    row = len(data)-1
    prev = row-1

    while row > 0 and prev >= 0:
        if data[row][-1] == 0:
            while prev >= 0 and data[prev][-1] == 0:
                prev -= 1
            data[row][-1] = data[prev][-1]
            data[prev][-1] = 0
        row -= 1
        prev -= 1        

    return data

# --- test ---

examples = [
  {
    'data': [[0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]],
    'expected': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]],
   },
  {
    'data': [[0, 0, -1], [1, 0, -2], [2, 0, -3], [3, 0, 0]],
    'expected': [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [3, 0, -3]],
   },
]

for ex in examples:
    print(ex['data'])
    result = move(ex['data'])
    print(ex['expected'])
    print(result == ex['expected']) # True
```

I use `rows = len(data)` and `[-1]` so it can have any size.

External `while` check if place `row` is empty and start internal `while` which is looking for not-empty elements `prev` before `row`. After that it move non-empty element from `prev` to `row` and put zero in `prev`. And it starts again with next `row` place.

It looks more complicated then other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I also handle the case if there was a 0 in the middle? I updated my initial question with more info showcasing that scenario. Thanks

Comment: add in question example with expected result. it helps to create and test solution.

Comment: If you look at the data and expected, I updated those values in my original question post: data = [[0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]]

expected = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]]

Comment: You should show your new example at start - now better create new question because current answers will not match your question.

Comment: first example can be done with `data[count], data[count-1] = data[count-1], data[count]`. second need more works. Better create new question because new examples need different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonably efficient way to do this. We grab the last column of the grid into a list named `lastcol`, and then sort `lastcol` with a key function that tests if each item is not equal to zero. That will move all the zeros to the start of `lastcol` without disturbing the order of the other elements. And then we copy `lastcol` back to the grid.

I've modified your test data slightly so that we can see that the code handles gaps and positive & negative values correctly.

```
grid = [[0, 0, -1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, -3], [4, 0, 0]]
print(grid)

lastcol = [u[-1] for u in grid]
lastcol.sort(key=(0).__ne__)
for row, u in zip(grid, lastcol):
    row[-1] = u
print(grid)
```

**output**

```
[[0, 0, -1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, -3], [4, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, -1], [3, 0, 2], [4, 0, -3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding the goal correctly -- that you'd want a column [0, 1, 0, 2, 3] to become [0, 0, 1, 2, 3] -- then with the use of a helper function to transpose the array, all we need to do is sort the columns using `bool` as the key function, because non-zero numbers are false, and False < True.

```
def transpose(seq):
    return [list(part) for part in zip(*seq)]

def push(seq):
    return transpose(sorted(part, key=bool) for part in transpose(seq))
```

which gives me

```
In [29]: push([[0, 0, -1], [1, 0, -2], [2, 0, -3], [3, 0, 0]])
Out[29]: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [3, 0, -3]]

In [30]: push([[0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]])
Out[30]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, -3], [0, 0, -4]]
```